# Highcharts AreaSpline Chart - Changing Color of each Point

Tags: highcharts

I have a Highchart with 'column' style and each column is a different color.  If I change the type to 'areaspline' (or 'area' for that matter) then the entire thing is one solid color.  Is there any way to retain the colors for each section?

Comment: can you post your chart code here or on http://jsfiddle.net/?

Answer (score 0):

Is this how your charting options look like?

```
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'areaspline'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Monthly Average Rainfall'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: WorldClimate.com'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: [
                'Jan',
                'Feb',
                'Mar',
                'Apr',
                'May',
                'Jun',
                'Jul',
                'Aug',
                'Sep',
                'Oct',
                'Nov',
                'Dec'
            ]
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Rainfall (mm)'
            }
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
            align: 'left',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: 100,
            y: 70,
            floating: true,
            shadow: true
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                return ''+
                    this.x +': '+ this.y +' mm';
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
            series: [{
            name: 'Tokyo',
            data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]

        }, {
            name: 'New York',
            data: [83.6, 78.8, 98.5, 93.4, 106.0, 84.5, 105.0, 104.3, 91.2, 83.5, 106.6, 92.3]

        }, {
            name: 'London',
            data: [48.9, 38.8, 39.3, 41.4, 47.0, 48.3, 59.0, 59.6, 52.4, 65.2, 59.3, 51.2]

        }, {
            name: 'Berlin',
            data: [42.4, 33.2, 34.5, 39.7, 52.6, 75.5, 57.4, 60.4, 47.6, 39.1, 46.8, 51.1]

        }]
    });
```

Fiddle @ http://jsfiddle.net/jugal/ZrTck/

Keep in mind to share your issues reproduced @ jsfiddle so that the community can help your correctly, quickly and easily.